# GWT application not working on iOS 8

Tags: gwt, ios8

Our GWT (2.5.1) web application stopped working for iOS 8. The page just stays blank and I cannot see any errors in the log.

The odd thing is that the app works fine if compiled with the "-style PRETTY" option.

I've found a few problems reported for iOS 8 and javascript but nothing related to my issue.

**Update:** The problem seems to be related to Safari rather than iOS. Using Chrome on the same phone, the application works fine.

Comment: what version of GWT are you using?

Comment: I've edited the question with the GWT version

Comment: As you say there are no errors, did you debug on safari developer mode (requires a mac)? We use 2.7 and there are no issues. We had numerous issues with 2.5.1 but that was with ios6. I can only say that ios8 and 2.7 works very well in chrome and safari.

Comment: Does the safari work after cleaning caches? At least once?

Comment: No, it's not a cache problem.

Comment: Sorry, I can only suggest you try to grab a mac and debug the mobile safari.